# How to improve validation score

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, scikit-learn, time-series

I am working on time series classification. My data has 4 classes. I used this paper's architecture on my data [(1611.06455)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.06455.pdf). However, my results look like this :
[image: early stop at 145th epoch due to stationary val score.]. Here is a [link to my notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dSvzTLVk65i0Q0yUL_4O3xOoJILCz8wa?usp=sharing)

I understand I might be over-fitting, but what simplifications might help ?

Here is the architecture :

[image: NN architecture]

Shape of input data : `505,10000`

Here is the plot of loss vs epoch as suggested

[image]

Comment: Try to plot the loss vs number of epochs. Since you're not maximizing accuracy but minimizing the loss it's not guaranteed that your accuracy will always be increasing.

Comment: @AyanMitra don't forget to use `@user` for people to get notified.

Comment: @alexmolas  I have added the plot, if you would like to discuss the results. thanks

Comment: Looking at both training and validation accuracy (even in training accuracy you never go over 50%), your model suffers from both high bias and variance. 

Try to change architecture for a model that better captures your time series. e.g. use LSTM cells, and try to play with hyperparameters.